# What is the difference between Shia and Sunni recitations of Ayatul-Kursi?

Tags: shia-sunni, quran-recitation, surat-al-baqarah

Why do Sunnis only recite one verse and Shias recite three verses as Ayatul kursi ([Qur'an 2:255](https://quran.com/2/255))?

Answer (score 4):

That two verses after the main verse of Ayatul-Kursi (255/2) are not a part of Ayatul-Kursi, but we sometimes read them for more sanctification and reward (thavab).

The main verse (of Ayatul-Kursi) is:

> اللَّـهُ لَا إِلَـٰهَ إِلَّا هُوَ الْحَيُّ الْقَيُّومُ ۚ لَا
>   تَأْخُذُهُ سِنَةٌ وَلَا نَوْمٌ ۚ لَّهُ مَا فِي السَّمَاوَاتِ وَمَا فِي
>   الْأَرْضِ ۗ مَن ذَا الَّذِي يَشْفَعُ عِندَهُ إِلَّا بِإِذْنِهِ ۚ
>   يَعْلَمُ مَا بَيْنَ أَيْدِيهِمْ وَمَا خَلْفَهُمْ ۖ وَلَا يُحِيطُونَ
>   بِشَيْءٍ مِّنْ عِلْمِهِ إِلَّا بِمَا شَاءَ ۚ وَسِعَ كُرْسِيُّهُ
>   السَّمَاوَاتِ وَالْأَرْضَ ۖ وَلَا يَئُودُهُ حِفْظُهُمَا ۚ وَهُوَ
>   الْعَلِيُّ الْعَظِيمُ ﴿٢٥٥
>
> Allah - there is no deity except Him, the Ever-Living, the Sustainer
>   of [all] existence. Neither drowsiness overtakes Him nor sleep. To Him
>   belongs whatever is in the heavens and whatever is on the earth. Who
>   is it that can intercede with Him except by His permission? He knows
>   what is [presently] before them and what will be after them, and they
>   encompass not a thing of His knowledge except for what He wills. His
>   Kursi extends over the heavens and the earth, and their preservation
>   tires Him not. And He is the Most High, the Most Great. (255)
>   http://tanzil.net/#trans/en.sahih/2:255

Comment: Then, e.g., why in namaz-e-wahshat it's said to recite ayat-ul-kursi till *hum phee ha khaladoun*?

Comment: this is for vigilance in this pray.  مرحوم فلسفی فی رساله آیه الکرسی قال: والاحوط قراءة آیة الکرسی الی هم فیها خالدون ولو اتی بغیرالکیفیة المزکورة سهواً اعاده ولو کان بترک آیة من انّا انزلنا،و آیة الکرسی (فی الصلاه لیله الدفن)

Comment: don't you think reciting the same verse 255 two more times has got more value than reciting the later two?

Comment: http://www.khamenei.de/fatwas/further.htm:
Question:  About Ayat-al-Kursi: Some brethren recite Ayat-al-Kursi only till "Aliyul azeem", but others recite it till "hum feeha khaalidoon". Which of these two versions is the correct one?
Answer:  
The correct one is till "khaalidoon".